# how we can get the data of all sandbox user and apply hastag search android instagram?

Tags: android

I am developing an app that uses the Instagram API. While in sandbox mode, it seems as though instagram does not allow you to use any endpoint that requires the 'public_content' scope. That being said, when I submit the app for approval and request the 'public_content' permission to be approved, it is always returning back rejected.

now my question is, 
is it possible to get the data of any user without instagram approval. if is it possible then how????

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get data by http request like this:

> https://www.instagram.com/username/?__a=1

and the response is json format.